# Jmeter Load Testing with view result in table listner

Tags: jmeter

sample time and latency is diffrent in jmeter for same request when hit mutilpe times why

I want to analyse why there is time difference between sample time and latency ,when there is  1 thread user , 1 ramp up period and loop count is 10 these two values are changing for the same request when it is called multiple times ,any explanation for this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/al95g.png)

In the Image added Above you can see that sample time is varying for all the samples used , I am calling the same Api request again and again but every sample time and latency is diffe
rent for each sample

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to say anything without seeing your Test Plan and [jmeter.log](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) file preferably with [JMeter debug logging enabled](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging).

Moreover the reason may be on the system under test side.

Blind shot which could explain the difference between 1st and 2nd and onwards requests: by default [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) has `Same user on each iteration` box ticked, it means that the user from 2nd iteration is considered as a **returning** one, not as the "new" one which means:

- no [TCP handshake](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/TCP_handshake)
- no [SSL handshake](https://www.ssl.com/article/ssl-tls-handshake-ensuring-secure-online-interactions/)
- no downloading embedded resources
- [cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies) which are received previously are being sent via [Cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cookie) header which means session restoration instead of creating the new one
- etc

Comment: I have  added image of my J meter performance report have look at it and give any explanation possible